# Issue while building ionic-angular project for latest xcode

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

angular project for iOS which is targeting latest xcode, but while compiling its giving this error against this `ionic capacitor sync ios --verbose` command

```
  src/comet-chat/src/components/Messages/CometChat-messages/cometchat-messages/cometchat-messages.component.ts:20:16
    20   templateUrl: "./cometchat-messages.component.html",
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CometChatMessagesComponent.


Error: src/comet-chat/src/components/Messages/Extensions/CometChat-create-poll/cometchat-create-poll/cometchat-create-poll.component.html:72:20 - error TS2739: Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<any>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange

72                   [formControl]="option"
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/comet-chat/src/components/Messages/Extensions/CometChat-create-poll/cometchat-create-poll/cometchat-create-poll.component.ts:15:16
    15   templateUrl: "./cometchat-create-poll.component.html",
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CometChatCreatePollComponent.


Error: src/comet-chat/src/components/Messages/Extensions/CometChat-message-reactions/cometchat-message-reactions/cometchat-message-reactions.component.html:29:49 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

29     <ngx-emoji [emoji]="reaction?.reactionName" size="16"></ngx-emoji>
                                                   ~~~~

  src/comet-chat/src/components/Messages/Extensions/CometChat-message-reactions/cometchat-message-reactions/cometchat-message-reactions.component.ts:21:16
    21   templateUrl: "./cometchat-message-reactions.component.html",
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CometChatMessageReactionsComponent.



[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
        
        ng run app:build --verbose exited with exit code 1.
```

I tried to update `@angular/compiler` to its latest version but still errors is same.